# How to get multiple sites served on different paths, Ubuntu Server 14 LTS and apache

Tags: apache, cakephp, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-14.04, http-status-code-403

Installed apache, mysql and php on Ubuntu Server 14 LTS. Also:

- CakePhp is installed in /srv/appName
- Phpmyadmin is installed in /usr/share/phpmyadmin (as recommended)
- A dummy home page is under default location /var/www/html/

I'd like to have sites served like this (links borked to get past the posting rules):

- httx://10.x.x.x/ -- home page
- httx://10.x.x.x/appName -- the cakePhp installation
- httx://10.x.x.x/phpmyadmin --- the PhpMyAdmin site

For a while I had Phpmyadmin working at the above URL with password authentication (thru html form), and the home page displaying, but could not get the cakePhp home page to show up.

Finally got the cakePhp home page to be served on httx://10.x.x.x/ , but only by changing 'DocumentRoot' value from /var/www/html to  /srv/appName/webroot  in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf .

Accessed this way, the cakePhp home page appears correct, with green checkmarks for directory permissions, database access and other setup -- but then of course the home page was no longer available.  Also at this time, Phpmyadmin started expecting http-authentication and giving 401 after rejecting all the username + passwords combos that previously worked thru HTML forms (tho I have not changed any config of Phpmyadmin).

Currently the home page appears, but the url with path /appName gets 403 and the one with /phpmyadmin gets the http-auth popup.

/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf is exactly as installed, no changes since Phpmyadmin was accessible. It contains:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
...
```

I also created /etc/appName/apache.conf on the model of /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf , including lines:

```
Alias /appName /srv/appName
<Directory /srv/appName>
...
```

Relevant (?) parts of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf :

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
Include /etc/appName/apache.conf

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

# changed "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All"
<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

# changed "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All"
<Directory /var/www>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
</Directory>

# added this and changed "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All"
<Directory /srv/appName>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

... 

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
```

I've read many forum posts and tried many different variations of all the above items. How can I get the default home page to be served on httx://10.x.x.x/ , the cakePhp on httx://10.x.x.x/appName , and PhpMyadmin on httx://10.x.x.x/phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

I would use symlinks, for example:

```
ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
```

Will put a pointer in /var/www/html:

```
phpmyadmin -> /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

And produce the same results as if phpmyadmin were in /var/www/html/